# Trying to turn the factorial part into another function

Tags: c, function, sum, factorial

I have to begin my thanking you guys for the help. I am trying to turn the factorial part of the code into another function and was wondering if I needed to add everything within the

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int num;
    int indx;
    int arrayIndx;
    int accumulator;
    int fact;
    int individualDigit[50];
    int length;

for(indx = 99999; indx > 0; indx--)
{

    num = indx;
    for (length = 0; num > 0; length++)
    {
        individualDigit[length] = num % 10;
        num /= 10;
        }

        accumulator = 0;
        for (arrayIndx = 0; arrayIndx < length; arrayIndx++)
        {
            fact = 1;
            while(individualDigit[arrayIndx] > 0)
            {
                fact*= individualDigit[arrayIndx];
                individualDigit[arrayIndx]--;
            }
            accumulator += fact;
        }

        if(accumulator == indx)
        {
            printf("%d ", accumulator);
        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should really consider indenting your code.

Comment: Why do you print the accumulated value only if `accumulator == indx`? What is the rationale behind this condition? Why not just print `accumulator` unconditionally?

Comment: I do it to see if its actually adding up the values from the factorial.

Comment: Also, please choose better names for your loop variables. Looking at `index`, `indx` and `idex`, I feel like in a [maze of twisty passages, all different](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/08/22/you-are-in-a-maze-of-twisty-little-passages-all-alike).

Comment: it is in the for statement.

Comment: If that were the case, you could just forgo the summation and print out `indx`. But the sum of digit factorials isn't the same as the number itself, obviously.

Comment: @MOehm by  doing the same thing I did with accumulator? Something like this?   *accumulator = 0;
            total = accumulator;
        accumulator+= total;*

Comment: Look at Serge's answer. In general, your program suffers from being too complicated. Loop over the digits, accumulate the factorials and then just print the accumulated value. That's all. No need for an auxilary array or for that many variables, really.

Answer (score 2):

You program is badly designed. It is not indented, you are using variable names `index`, `indx` and `idex` which is confusing for the reader and would lead to nightmares for long term maintenance. Also the factorial computation would deserve to be in a function for better modularity.

But apart from that, your program does what you ask, correctly computes factorials and adds them in the `accumulator` variable. The only problem is that you never print that accumulator except for the last 2 cases (2 and 1) where `n = n!`.

Simply replace :

```
if (accumulator == indx)
{
printf("\n%d\n", indx);
}
```

with

```
printf("\n%d\n", accumulator);
```

and you will see your results.

If you want to store the sum of factorials in an array, you just have to declare `int sumOfFact[26] = {0};` just before `int individualDigit[50];` to define the array and initialize `sumOfFact[0]` to 1, and then add `sumOfFact[indx] = accumulator;` just before printing the accumulator.

---

To put the factorial part in a function, it is quite simple. First declare it above your main:

```
int ffact(int n);
```

the define it anywhere in your code (eventually in another compilation unit - a .c file - if you want)

```
inf ffact(int n) {
    fact = 1;
    while (n > 1) {
        fact *= n--;
        /* if (fact < 0) { fprintf(stderr, "Overflow in ffact(%d)\n", n); return 0; } */
    }
    return fact
}
```

I commented out the test for overflow, because I assume you use at least 32 bits int and fact(9) will not overflow (but fact(13) would ...)

The loop computing the sum of factorials becomes:

```
accumulator = 0;
for (arrayIndx = 0; arrayIndx < length; arrayIndx++)
{
    accumulator += ffact(individualDigit[arrayIndx]);
}
printf("\n%d\n", accumulator);
```

Advantages for that modularity: it is simpler to separately test the code for ffact. So when things go wrong, you have not to crawl among one simple piece of code of more than 40 lines (not counting the absent but necessaries comments). And the code no longers clutters the `individualDigit` array.

Comment: Thanks for the help I cleaned it up a lot and are trying to turn the factorial equation into a function but can't.

Comment: Thank you. What exactly do you mean by overflow?

Comment: @RichardFlores: On common architectures, and int is represented with 32 bits, the most significant being the sign bit. 12! is 479001600 or 0x1c8cfc00 in hexdecimal, and 13!  is 6227020800 or 0x17328cc00 in hexa. As it uses more than 32 bits, if you do not test anything, you will get 0x7328cc00 or 1932053504 which is incorrect. If you test, 13*12*..*3 gives 3113510400 or 0xb9946600 which represents a negative value : -1181456896. Welcome to the world of processors :-)